# How to create a thank you page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to create a thank you page, my route for this works fine since I test it the url and works just fine, however when I try to redirect in the create action I get:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"thank_you", :locale=>:en, :controller=>"appointments"}
```

Controller

```
  def create
    @appointment = Appointment.new(params[:appointment])

      if @appointment.save
        #send email
        AppointmentMailer.appointment_confirmation(@appointment).deliver
        AppointmentMailer.new_appointment(@appointment).deliver
        redirect_to :action => "thank_you"
      else
        render :action => 'new', :alert => @appointment.errors.full_messages.split(', ')
      end
  end


  def thank_you
      @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Route

```
resources :appointments, :except => :new do
      member do
        get :thank_you
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [add it as a RESTful action](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) (or assume a default matching route).

Nutshell:

```
resources :appointments do
  member do
    get 'thank_you'
  end
end
```

Or:

```
resources :appointments do
  get 'thank_you', :on => :member
end
```

Comment: I did, I've added the route code to the pos, and still getting the error.

Comment: yes. No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"schedules", :locale=>:en, **:id=>nil**}. @DaveNewton

Comment: @evanx That's a *completely* different route, resource, and error.

Comment: You are absolutely right @DaveNewton, I restared the server and now that's the error I get, would you like me to add another piece of code to check where the error comes from?

Comment: @evanx No, if it's a different question, ask a new question--IMO this one is asked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

For getting a new page, you have to do more than just editing the controller.

1. Edit config/routes.rb and include

   ```
   match "/appointments/thank_you" => "appointments#thank_you"
   ```
2. You might want to insert `render` command in the controller, that brings you to a thank you view you have to create...

Comment: IMO if it's a standard resource it's cleaner to use the existing `resources` routes. Also, recent Rails versions do [default, convention-based rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action).